# stop and continue JavaScript execution

Tags: php, javascript

i am trying to create an application for in PHP such that after the submission, the system should retrieve all the applications which he had done earlier and ask him whether to continue or not.

the logic is in such a way that i hav a div (id : confirmation) whose display is none. when the execution is on progress, we fetch all the details, write to div, then display will be 'block';

there will be two hyper links in confirmation div , confirm, and abort. when i click on confirm, the execution should continue to save the application.

the pain area is that everything is going fine except the div is not waiting for the confirmation. it is just coming and execution is continuing. it is not waiting for user confirmation.

somebody please tell me how to stop execution for user confrmation

thanks in advancce

Jessy

Comment: We can't answer this without seeing your code.

Comment: Can you show us some of your code?

Comment: i did it like  <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onmousemove="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block'">click here</a> and it is working. but i need to do it automatically during execution. please help me.

Comment: it is html light box like http://www.emanueleferonato.com/downloads/lightbox.html My code is like <?php //fetch all values using post; retreve values from database; if(row num > 0> { //show the confirmation div} else continue PHP execution and save to database

Comment: Can you edit your post and paste the entire relevant section of code?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to have a a function that is called when the confirm is clicked instead of continuing execution.  JavaScript doesn't stop when a modal is presented (unless it's from a confirm() or alert() dialog).